# How to handle optional fields from Firestore in flutter Map constructor?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a Firebase Firestore with a `centa_tasks` collection that contains documents that contain fields that may or may not include `location` of type String.

**Data Structure:**

[image]

I have a `Task` class that takes a `DocumentSnapshot` as seen bellow:

```
class Task {
  final int status;
  final String site;
  final String location;
  final String id;
  final DocumentReference reference;

  Task.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map, {this.id, this.reference})
      : assert(map['site'] != null),
        assert(map['status'] != null),
        assert(map['location'] != null),
        site = map['site'],
        status = map['status'],
        location = map['location'];

  Task.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot)
      : this.fromMap(snapshot.data,id: snapshot.documentID, reference: snapshot.reference);

}
```

The issue is this, not all documents contain the field `location` so when a task is passed that does not contain `location` in the map the null assertion fails.

How do I allow for an optional key in the map in the constructor?

Thank you
Brandon Pillay

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you should remove this assertion,

> assert(map['location'] != null)

then

```
location = (map['location']!=null)? map['location'] : 'noData';
```

The above code sets location to 'noData' if it is null, then in your code you can check if location == 'noData' to know the absence of location.